# select box auto select use for many div content in html

Tags: html

I want to use auto select for select box in many div.
How can I use auto select for many time like software method.
I not want to write many time for select box class name.
My example:
select box auto select not work in second div(divTwo) and click divTwo's option change divOne's option.Not change clicked div individually.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".a1").change(function(){
        $(".a2 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
        $(".a3 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
    });
    $(".a2").change(function(){
        $(".a1 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
        $(".a3 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
    });

    $(".a3").change(function(){
        $(".a1 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
        $(".a2 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex")).prop("selected", "selected");
    });
});

<div class="divOne">
    <select class=" a1" >
        <option >Option1</option>
        <option >Option2</option>
        <option >Option3</option>
    </select>
    <select class=" a2" >
        <option >Option1</option>
        <option >Option2</option>
        <option >Option3</option>
    </select>
    <select class=" a3" >
        <option >Option1</option>
        <option >Option2</option>
        <option >Option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="divTwo">
    <select class=" a1" >
        <option >Option1</option>
        <option >Option2</option>
        <option >Option3</option>
    </select>
    <select class=" a2" >
        <option >Option1</option>
        <option >Option2</option>
        <option >Option3</option>
    </select>
    <select class=" a3" >
        <option >Option1</option>
        <option >Option2</option>
        <option >Option3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$([selector])
```

This always returns an array of jquery objects which match the selector. You think it is returning an array of 3 elements. But it is returning an array of 6 elements.

```
$(".a1 option")
```

This returns an array(6) of all the options under `<select class="a1">`. These are both under DIV ONE and DIV TWO. Due to their sequence in HTML the options under DIV ONE are listed first in the array of elements.

```
$(".a1 option").eq($(this).prop("selectedIndex"))
```

This will make a new jQuery object for DIV ONE > A1 > options[selectedIndex]. This is because of the above mentioned reason. Hence on every change DIV ONE options are selected ALWAYS (because they are first in the array of options with selector .a1 option).

**SOLUTION**

You need to specify under which div do you want to make changes automatically.
I think you want all the selectors under same div to change simultaneously.

I have used `$(this).parent()` to specify the div. Then find the desired select option.

Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgutpLj9/).